# Number of combinations formula

Tags: combinations

Show that:

$\binom{n+1}{2} = \binom{n}{2} + n$

I think I am supposed to use the number of Combinations formula:

$ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-k+1))}{k(k-1)(k-2)..1)} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

I tried to use the formula on the LHS and got this:

$\frac{(n+1)!}{2(n-1)}$

Comment: This is just [Pascal's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule) $\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}$ for the special case of $k=2$.

Comment: Recheck what you get on the LHS. How many factorials should it have?

Answer (score 1):

You can also argue "combinatorically":

- LHS: all selections of $2$ items from $n+1$ items: $\binom{n+1}{2}$
- RHS: fix the first $n$ items of the $1 \ldots n \; (n+1)$ items, take all selections of $2$ out of these $n$ items and all selections consisting of item $(n+1)$ and one of the first $1 \ldots n$ items: $\binom{n}{2} + n$

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution:

$ \binom{n+1}{2} = \frac{(n+1)!}{2(n-1)!} = \frac{(n+1)n!}{(n-1)2!(n-2)!} = \frac{n!}{2(n-2)!} * \frac{n+1}{n-1} = $

$ = \binom{n}{2} * (1 + \frac{2}{n-1}) = \binom{n}{2} + \frac{2n!}{(n-1)2(n-2)!} = \binom{n}{2} + n $

However i don't understand this part:

$  \binom{n}{2} * \frac{n+1}{n-1}  = \binom{n}{2} * (1 + \frac{2}{n-1}) $

How can this be true?

Comment: Observe that $$\frac{n + 1}{n - 1} = \frac{n - 1 + 2}{n - 1} = \frac{n - 1}{n - 1}  + \frac{2}{n - 1} = 1 + \frac{2}{n - 1}$$ which implies the result you were questioning.

Comment: Yes thanks is there a name for that relation? I remember seeing it before.

Comment: The relation $$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n - 1}{k} + \binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$$ is called [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule), or have I misunderstood your question?